# SAS EG Import Data Error - Delimiter and column not recognized

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am very new to SAS and would like to import a CSV file into SAS. I have tried using proc and also the tool import data, but fail to import the data.

i get the following errors:

1. ERROR: The name Page Name (prop31) is not a valid SAS name
2. when importing the data it doesnt accept the delimiter and imports everything as one column

any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you tell it what delimiter to use?  Are you running PROC IMPORT code? Show the code. Or just pushing buttons in Enterprise Guide? Describe the sequence of buttons you pushed.

Comment: Show the code used to import data or at least a screenshot of what you selected in the GUI.